# how to check whether word in wordNet or not

Tags: java, jaws-wordnet

I start to learn about `wordNet` and till know I found the `synonymous` for a specific word 
now I have a file and I want to tokenize this text using `n-gram` for example

```
String s="I like to wear tee shirt";
```

after using `n-gram` it will be

```
I
like
to 
wear 
tee 
shirt
.
.
.
wear tee
tee shirt
```

and so on 
and then I want to know if `tee shirt` is a `biword` (I can consider it as one word in the search index)
so I thought to use wordNet to check whether (tee shirt) in wordNet or not

`if True` then it is a biword and have a synonymous for example jersey, T-shirt, tee shirt

`if false` then it is Not

is there any method in `Jaws` check if this word in wordnet or not??
or I should see if the word has a synonymous then it's by default in it (as a solution I thought of)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem since no one  answer the question 
I will post what the answer for future visitor that will have the same problem
I hope that will be useful :)

```
public static boolean is_Missing_WordNet(String r,String posTag){
   // System.out.println("inside is_missing_Wordnet "+r);
          boolean flag=true;
              configureJWordNet();
              Dictionary dictionary = Dictionary.getInstance();
              IndexWord word;
        try {
            if(posTag.equals("VBG"))//Verb
                 { word = dictionary.lookupIndexWord(POS.VERB, r);}
            else {word = dictionary.lookupIndexWord(POS.NOUN, r);}

            Synset[] senses = word.getSenses();

                if(senses!=null && senses.length>0){
                 if(senses[0].toString().toLowerCase().contains(r)|| senses[0].toString().contains(r.replace(" ","_")))
                 { System.out.println("sense;;;; "+senses[0].toString());flag=false;}
                  }                                       
                else{System.out.println("wordnet has no sense of "+r );return true; }


                }
        catch(NullPointerException ex){return true;}
         catch (JWNLException ex) {return true;
                    }
        return flag; 
    }
```

this function return true if it is missing from WordNet dictionary

Comment: Hi I would like to use this code. What is the body of `configureJWordNet()` and what needs to be imported?